# Apache flume rolling out the HDFS files on hourly basis

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I'm new to Flume and I was exploring options to roll over my HDFS files on hourly basis using Flume.

In my project Apache Flume will read the messages from Rabbit MQ and it will write it to HDFS.

**`hdfs.rollInterval`** - It closes the file based on the time interval when it got opened.

New file will be created only when Flume reads a message after the file got closed. This option is not solving our problem.

**`hdfs.path = /%y/%m/%d/%H`** - This option is working fine and it creates folder on hourly basis. But the problem is new folder will be created only when new message comes.

For example: Messages are coming till 11.59, the file will be in open state. Then the messages stop coming till 12.30. But, the file will still be in open state. After 12.30 new message comes. Then because of **hdfs.path** configuration, previous file will be closed and new file will be created in new folder.

Previous file cannot be used for computation till it is closed.

We need an option of closing the opened files on hourly basis perfectly. I'm wondering if there any options in flume for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

[hdfs.rollInterval](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink) is described as

> Number of seconds to wait before rolling current file

So this line should cause the files to allocate for an hour at a time

```
hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
```

And I would additionally ignore file size and event count, so add these as well

```
hdfs.rollSize = 0
hdfs.rollCount = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

hdfs.idleTimeout

Timeout after which inactive files get closed (0 = disable automatic closing of idle files)

For example, you can set this property to 180. The file will be opened